# Getting error when adding ng-zorro-antd with cli in angular 8 ng add ng-zorro-antd

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

Having this issue when adding ng-zorro-antd with cli in angular 8.
Followed the steps:

1. ng new PROJECT_NAME
2. cd PROJECT_NAME
3. ng add ng-zorro-antd

My Configurations are:

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.1
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          7.2.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.12.1 (cli-only)
```

Comment: what kind of error? - try npm install ng-zorro-antd

Comment: Just resolved my self by updating dependencies and and editing tsconfig.json file by changing module:"es2015" to "esnext"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by following these steps:

```
npm update @angular/cli @angular/cdk rxjs
npm install -S @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
npm uninstall @angular/core
npm install -S @angular/core
```

and after this changing module:"es2015" to module:"esnext" in tsconfig.json by